# convert text to dd/mm/yyyy format

Tags: excel, text

How do I convert the following text into dd/mm/yyyy format, in excel:-

```
24032006 
 2042005
19012008
 2092001
```

The expected results should be:-

```
24/03/2006
02/04/2005
19/01/2008
02/09/2001
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NEW ANSWER**
Try this formula -

```
=TEXT(DATE(MOD(A1,10^4),MOD(INT(A1/10^4),10^2),INT(A1/10^6)),"dd/mm/yyyy")
```

Assuming the text `"20122010"` in date format is in cell `A1`

**OLD ANSWER**

Assuming you will use some coding language to get this done, You can first check the length of string is 8. If its 7, then add 0 to front of string to make it 8. Then you can just insert '/' after two characters and get the string in dd/MM/yyyy format.

Comment: I'm not using any coding. Any formulas ??

Comment: @Bob - Edited my answer to include excel formula

Answer (score 0):

'mm' represents minutes, your format should be 'dd/MM/yyyy'